# Does wealth index created in stata (command: pca and predict) considers all the components whoese eigen value more than 1 or just first component?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, stata

I am trying to calculate the wealth index of a rural community of Nepal. For this, I used 10 household assets variables after conducting a descriptive analysis. I used the principal component analysis. I got the first four components have more than 1 eigenvalue, those four component explains 54% of the variance (the first component explains only 17.9%). The KMO measure of sampling adequacy is 0.619, Bartlett's test of sphericity is <0.001. Now, I am confused about the following things:

1. Does the wealth index create (by predict command) considers all component those eigenvalue is more than 1 or just the first component? If it is only the first component then, does it means it only explains 17.9% variance?
2. If I add one more variable, it increases the total variance, Bartlett's test remains significant, but KMO measure drops to 0.599. Can we consider KMO 0.599 as 0.6 (as 0.6 is the minimum acceptable value)?
   Can I proceed with my study with the above results?
   Sorry If my question is not clear, I can explain it further if you want.
   Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much @Fcold, it's very much helpful. So, for example: 4 components which eigen value is more than 1, explains vairance as following comp1:  20 %, comp2:14%, comp3:12%, comp4: 10%. So if wealth index is created it considers first component, but while reporting, can we say our model explains 56% or just 20%. Thank you, I hope, I am not bothering you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your second question. You are still at the limit of KMO test, on the other hand, if those new variables make theoretical sense, I would go ahead and include them.
Regarding the first question.
the short answer is no. If you do the following:

```
pca x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
predict index1
```

the "index1" will consider only the first component, which is the idea behind a wealth index.
The other components you are interested in could be used perhaps for a multidimensional index that captures different dimensions of wealth.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much @Fcold, it's very much helpful. So, for example: 4 components which eigen value is more than 1, explains variance as following comp1: 20 %, comp2:14%, comp3:12%, comp4: 10%. So if wealth index is created it considers the first component, but while reporting, can we say our model explains 56% or just 20%. Thank you, I hope, I am not bothering you 

Comment: Just 20%, because that is how much the first component explains.

Comment: Thank you very much :) @Fcold